# Play framework: Store connections after onStart?

Tags: java, session, caching, playframework, elasticsearch

I'm writing a RESTful API using the Play Framework and I have some bootstrap operations on application start;

```
Client transClient = new TransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(ESHost, 9300));
```

Which is quite basic, I establish a connection to an `ElasticSearch` cluster. Now, I want `transClient` to be accessible across `packages/controllers/etc`, and one workaround could be to `Cache.set("ES", transClient)`, which ofcourse doesn't seem right.

I cannot find any documentation about this online. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is a singleton. You don't even have to bootstrap it in the global *onStart* method.

```
public class ConnectionHolder {

    private static ConnectionHolder holder;
    private Client transClient = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(ESHost, 9300));

    private ConnectionHolder() {   }

    static ConnectionHolder getInstance() {
        return holder == null ? holder = new ConnectionHolder() : holder;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return transClient;
    }

}
```

**tl;dr**

In my current project we use the Guice singleton scope for this kind of problems. So we can easily inject anything to controllers or services. There's a lot advantages of this solution especially during tests. If you don't have any dependency injection framework in your project a simple singleton will do the job. Solving thread safe problems is up to you.

Comment: That is by far the best solution I've come across. Thanks!